# Meromorphic function written as Weierstrass Elliptic Function

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces

Let $\Lambda$ be a lattice in the complex plane. And Weierstrass Elliptic Function

$$\wp(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{\omega \in \Lambda - \{0\}}\frac{1}{(z-\omega)^2}-\frac{1}{\omega ^2}$$

How can I show that every $\Lambda $-periodic meromorphism function $f$ with poles of order 2 only at the lattice points can be written as

$$f = a \wp +b$$

where $a,b\in \mathbb C$ and $a$ is non-zero.

Comment: I have shown (from part a of the question) that $\wp (z)$ is a $\Lambda$-periodic meromorphism function and clearly it has poles of order 2, than isn't that trivial to say we can write other $\Lambda$-mero function in term of $\wp (z)$?

Comment: What can you say about the residue of $f$ at the poles? Then consider a suitable difference.

Comment: residue is $0$? Since the pole is of order $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
\frac{a_{-2}}{z^2} + \frac {a_{-1}}z
$$
be the principal part of $f$ at $z = 0$. For an elliptic function, the sum of all residues at the poles in a fundamental parallelogram is zero,
therefore 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\res}{Res}
a_{-1} = \res (f; 0) = 0 \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
f(z) - a_{-2} \wp(z)
$$
is an elliptic function without poles and therefore constant.